# Tenant Admin Cannot Login into the Tenant After the Tenant is created

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I created a tenant in abp using the admin. But i was unable to login with the email address used in the tenant registration. I also queried the database and looks like it is not being saved.

Comment: Apperantly dataseeder didn't work for your case. Did the tenant created? 
Abp supports more than one template, so providing more information will help to solve the problem. Such as; which template did you come across? Angular or MVC ui? Separate identity server application? Did you also try running DbMigrator to see if it seeds the admin user for tenant?

Comment: I'm using angular UI with abp commercial. The tenants get created if data seeder project is run, but once i create the tenant the email i use in admin email cannot be used to login.  The abp framework version is 4.3.2. I also query the database and looks like the admin user is not being saved to the user table.